# Semi-additive DBT metric based on BQ SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, business-intelligence, dbt

I have a BigQuery table with a slightly strange structure. There are 3 sets of metric names + values that are unrelated. Previously, the table was very wide but we have deliberately unpivoted many metric columns into column pairs (metric name + value).

The data looks like the below (sensitive info redacted).

[image]

Each of the metric values are semi-additive. They can be aggregated across other dimensions (date, brand_group) but not across the unrelated dimensions - or this would lead to double counting. Therefore, when aggregating, we should select ANY_VALUE() from a partition window before aggregating further.

Logically, this is quite achievable with a DBT metric definition that looks like the following:

```yaml
...
calculation_method: sum
expression: "ANY_VALUE(`nielsen_metric_value`) OVER (PARTITION BY `date`, `brand_group`, `nielsen_metric_name`)"
...
```

I believe the problem is BQ-specific. You cannot aggregate analytics functions. The general workaround here would be to use a sub-query but that can't work in a DBT metric context (e.g. [Combining windowed and aggregate functions in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051315/combining-windowed-and-aggregate-functions-in-bigquery)).

At the moment, I understand my options are either:

- Implement this downstream of DBT - I can do this in my BI tool but I'd rather not lose the centralisation of the metric.
- Change the structure of the data. We deliberately moved to this structure so downstream use cases can select the metric name as a dimension because otherwise, this dataset has a huge range of metrics. Of course, we could separate out the 3 pairs of metrics but they are together deliberately because they are related and share the common dimensions of date and brand_group.

**Can anyone conceive of a better way?**

[image]